# Create save file dialog with encoding combobox choices like Notepad

Tags: vb.net, encoding, notepad, savefiledialog

I'm trying to create a savefiledialog to save the text found in a richtextbox

but with different choices for encoding like notepad:

[image]

the problem for me is that combobox which allow for different encoding

how could i add it to the savefiledialog, this is my code:

```
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBox1.Text, False)
        End If
```

Comment: [Extending the save file dialog class in .NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8086/Extending-the-save-file-dialog-class-in-NET)

Comment: The *real* method implies the use of the [IFileDialogCustomize](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialogcustomize). Something similar is shown here: [Using GetEditBoxText in IFileSaveDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35309166/7444103). Unfortunately, to implement this in VB.Net (or C#) you have to re-implement all the native interfaces, from `IFileDialog` to `IFileDialogEvents`. The .Net component does that, but all the native objects are `private` or `internal` (who knows why, even the Delphi dialogs expose the `IFileDialog` interface)

Comment: @Jimi, thanks, i'll try that method

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify the [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_FileDialog_Filter) property of the SaveFileDialog:

```vb
Using sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
    With sfd
        .Filter = "Text|*.txt|Word|*.docx|Etc|*.etc"

        If (sfd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.Ok Then
            '...
        End If
    End With
End Using
```

Comment: Not the `Save as type` selection Combo, the `Encoding` Combo :)

Comment: @Jimi doh! I'm sorry about that. I'm not sure that you can using the default SaveFileDialog, you'd have to create a custom dialog.

Comment: It's in the link I posted (above). If you care to implement it for VB.Net, there's a comment with some good notes in that post (and a lot of the code).